# index seek while calling the UDF itself, index scan while wrapping the UDF in sp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that does most of the joins and when I run it, it read about 100-150 pages (from sql profiler) but if I wrap this UDF in sp then the sp will do the read about 243287 pages.

Furthermore, the UDF itself performs index seek but the sp performs index scan on one of the searched columns.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are asking.

Comment: okay..let me try again.. I have the UDF (say pullingCustomerUDF) and it is taking 3 parameters. If I call the UDF with select statement (e.g. select * from pullingCustomerUDF('param1', 'parm2', 'param3'), it is working fine with reading 110 pages (within 100 microsecs). However if I include the select statement within a stored proc and execute the stored proc, it will then read 243287 pages within 5-7 seconds. any ideas?

Comment: pleas also note that the stored proc does not contain any other code other than the select statement!

Comment: ok found the problem but i can't explain myself why. I had the comparison like this: (custid = @param1 OR @param1 is null) and when I removed the "is null" and becoming like this: (custid = @param1) then the stored proc is now executed so quickly. can anyone explain? I also SET ANSI_NULLS ON but no luck

Comment: Interesting you must have confused the query optimizer into doing a sequential read of the table, maybe.

Comment: which type is your udf - scalar, inline, or multi-statement?

Comment: the udf is returning a table.

Comment: Inline table or multi statement table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments about `(custid = @param1 OR @param1 is null)` vs. `(custid = @param1)`, I think Gail Shaw's blog posting on [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) will provide some insight into what you're seeing here. Basically, I think you're getting an execution plan cached for the `@param1 is null` case that then performs poorly when you pass in a real `@param1`.

Comment: the how do i refresh the excution plan. I also tried to create the stored proc with RECOMPILE option but it didn't fix the execution plan

Comment: REcompile won't fix this. SQL generates bad plans for this pattern of queries. See my blog post (referenced above), or change the query so that the parameter is no longer optional.